# SKPhysicsBody slowing down program

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I have a random maze generator that starts building small mazes then progress into massive levels. The "C"s are collectables and the "T"s are tiles. the "P" is the player starting position. I included a sample tile map below.

The performance issue is not when I have a small 6x12 pattern like here; it shows up when I've got a 20x20 pattern for example.

Each character is a tile, and each tile has it's own `SKPhysicsBody`. The tiles are not square, they are complex polygons and the tiles don't quite touch each other.

The "C"s need to be able to be removed one at a time, and the "T"s are permanent for the level and don't move. Also the maze only shows 6x4 section of tiles at a time and moves the background to the view centered on the player.

**I've tried making the T's and C's rectangles which drastically improves performance (but still slower than desired) although the user won't care for this, the shape of the tile is just too different.**

Are there any performance tricks you pros can muster up to fix this?

```
TTTTTT
TCTTCT
TCCCCT
TTCTCT
TCCTCT
TTCCTT
TTTCTT
TTCCCT
TCCTCT
TCTTCT
TTCCCT
TTPTTT
```

Comment: That's 400 physics bodies with complex shapes, which is quite a lot. Improve their shape to use the minimal number of vertices that create the required collision behavior. Note that it is very common for physics shapes to have only a very roughly defined shape. The spaceship posted by Stefan could indeed work well enough with just 3 vertices, maybe 5 to 9 at most depending on how accurate things really need to be. You may want to consider spacing them apart so they won't generate collisions every frame, too.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I was hoping you'd see this question. I use 8 points and while it is decent enough on my iPhone 6, the 4s isn't doing so hot. I was thinking maybe there was an easy way to load the physics bodies while they were within a certain position of the view? And remove them when they are off the view. Would this make the processor crawl more than it already is?

Answer (score 1):

> The tiles are not square, they are complex polygons

I think this is your problem. Also, if your bodies are dynamic, setting them static will drastically improve performance. You can also try [pooling](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/object-pool.html). And be aware, that performance on the simulator is drastically lower than on the real device.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did try making them rectangles just to see if it would improve my performance to desired levels but even with that it's not where it needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of collision method are you using?

[image]

SpriteKit provides several possibilities to define the shape of the SKPhysicsBody. The best performance provides a rectangle or a circle:

```
myPhysicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: mySprite.size)
```

You can also define more complex shapes like a triangle, which have a worse performance.

Using the texture (SpriteKit will use all non transparent pixels to detect the shape by itself) has the worst performance:

```
myPhysicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: mySprite.texture, size: mySprite.size)
```

Activating 'usesPreciseCollisionDetection' will also have a negative impact on your performance.

Comment: The third one. I did note in my question I've tried making them rectangles but it just won't work for my purpose. `usesPreciseCollisionDetection` is off.

Comment: OK. Then I would try to use: bodyWithPolygonFromPath:(CGPathRef) path to define the shape of your polygon. It should be better then the texture

Comment: I'm using that since I support iOS 7. I think the big problem is that there are just so many physics bodies on the scene at one time, even though not all are reachable at all times. Is there a way to create/destory physics bodies as they move on/off scene? That might help me out significantly.

Comment: I had a comparable numbers of physics bodies on a screen. But only rectangles. I guess your tiles are mostly static and the dynamic flag is set to false?

Comment: After removing the nodes from the scene, the physics bodies should have no impact on the performance. Of course you should check, that no reference to the removed nodes is preventing ARC to remove them out of memory. That can have an performance impact after a while. Sorry, no other idea.